# Grouped 3 monthly aggregation and shifting periods in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

**The problem**

I have a dataframe with many regions and their respective units sold, visits performed and average visit times on a monthly basis. Not all the regions have the same starting date.

So my table looks something like this:

```
Region    Month       Visits  Average_minutes  Units_sold
Region_1  2018.01.01  12      2.22             120
Region_1  2018.02.01  10      2.02             108
Region_2  2017.04.01  4       1.8              60
Region_2  2017.05.01  4       1.6              56
Region_2  2017.06.01  3       1.5              58
Region_1  2018.03.01  11      2.1              103
Region_3  2018.04.01  3       2.22             20
Region_3  2018.05.01  2       2                22
Region_2  2017.07.01  6       1.7              61
Region_1  2018.04.01  14      2.1              125
Region_3  2018.06.01  3       2.3              21
Region_3  2018.07.01  3       2.4              19
Region_1  2018.05.01  10      2.12             116
Region_2  2017.08.01  3       2.1              55
```

What I would like to have is aggregate the monthly data for the different regions in 3 months frequencies by shifting one month forward.

So if we take Region_1 for example, the end result I would like to get is something like this:

```
Region    Date        Visits  Average_minutes  Units_sold  3M_shift
Region_1  2018.01.01  33      2.11             331         0
Region_1  2018.04.01  24      2.11             241         0
Region_1  2018.02.01  35      2.07             336         1
Region_1  2018.05.01  10      2.12             116         1
Region_1  2018.02.01  35      2.07             336         2
Region_1  2018.05.01  10      2.12             116         2
```

As you can see the Date now contains the starting date of the 3 month frequency and in the 3M_shift column I see the shifts made compared to the first available month.

Of course in the table above you can see Region_1 only but i would like to get this result for all the groups.

**More background**

So I would like to have data per groups aggregated not only business year quarters but on 3 month frequency shifting by one month forwards for every iteration till I get to the last month.

My code looks like this, but this groups the months from the starting date of each region and I don't really know how to shift the starting month by one and iterate till the last month:

```
grp = joined.groupby(['Region', pd.Grouper(key="Date", freq='3M')]).agg({"Visits":"sum", "Average_minutes":"mean", "Units_sold":"sum"})
```

So for Region_1 for example I get this result:

```
Region  Date          Visits  Average_minutes  Units_sold
Region_1  2018.01.01  33      2.11             331
Region_1  2018.04.01  24      2.11             241
```

Edit:
Added a better visualisation of what I would like to get.

In the picture below you can see what I mean. The green part is what I have so far. I would like to make a loop for the pink part, but I do not know how to do it.

[image]

Could you please help me to get the desired outcome?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you are looking for, but the way I interpret, maybe this will help?

First sort Region and Month.

```
df = df.sort_values(['Region', 'Month'])
```

The set a multi index.

```
df = df.set_index(['Region', 'Month'])
```

Then groupby the region and apply a rolling window for aggregating and shift it back two periods.

```
df = df.groupby(level='Region').apply(lambda x: x.rolling(window=3).agg({"Visits":"sum", "Average_minutes":"mean", "Units_sold":"sum"}).shift(-2))
```

The result is:

```
                     Visits  Average_minutes  Units_sold
Region   Month                                          
Region_1 2018.01.01    33.0         2.113333       331.0
         2018.02.01    35.0         2.073333       336.0
         2018.03.01    35.0         2.106667       344.0
         2018.04.01     NaN              NaN         NaN
         2018.05.01     NaN              NaN         NaN
Region_2 2017.04.01    11.0         1.633333       174.0
         2017.05.01    13.0         1.600000       175.0
         2017.06.01    12.0         1.766667       174.0
         2017.07.01     NaN              NaN         NaN
         2017.08.01     NaN              NaN         NaN
Region_3 2018.04.01     8.0         2.173333        63.0
         2018.05.01     8.0         2.233333        62.0
         2018.06.01     NaN              NaN         NaN
         2018.07.01     NaN              NaN         NaN
```

Comment: Hi run-out. Thank you very much for your comment. Unfortunately your solution is not what I am looking for.
It is my mistake that I could not explain clearly what I would like to get.
For more clarity I have added a picture to the bottom of my original post in order to provide a better understanding on what I would like to achieve.
Hopefully this will be more understandable! Thank you!

Comment: Could someone help me out with this problem please?

Comment: I would like to help buy I'm still not quite clear what you are looking for. Could you provide a clear sample results table/dataframe so I know what you are trying to accomplish? For example, it seems to me like the + 3 month shift in your table is the same as the green column. I'm not getting it.  Also the results table for region one repeats the same data from rows 3:4 in rows 5:6, which is also confusing. If you could be clear on your intended results we can take another look at it.

Comment: Thank you again run-out for your intention. So, your solution is good as first step to what I want to achieve. 
Basically your solution aggregates data based on 3 month window and then shifts it back by two months. This would be the first step to me. The next step for me would be to delete the 2018.01.01 month for Region_1 (as if it not existed) and then do the same (3 window, -2 shifts) process again. Then, again delete the 2018.02.01 data and repeat the (3 window, -2 shifts) process again. 
The same for Region_2 only in case of Region_2 the starting date is 2017.04.01.

Comment: So basically I would like to do your grouping and then delete the first data row and repeat the whole process (starting with the second month as starting point, because I deleted the first month). 
Is this way easier to understand?

Comment: But isn't that already there? If you just drop the first month, you'll already have the answer in the second month. Are you looking for new columns or a new dataframe?

Comment: Ohh...you might be right. So what happens for the Region_1, 2018.04.01 month data? If there are only two months (like 2018.04 and 2018.05) pandas will not aggregate them because of the window=3 argument? Do I understand it clearly?

Comment: You can restrict the starting point by filtering the original dataframe like this: df= df[df['Month']> '2018.01.01']

Comment: with only two months you don't have a 3 month average.

Comment: I've looked at the documentation for grouper and I don't see an option to fill if less the 3 months, but I could be wrong. Someone with more experience might help if you need that.

Comment: Hi run-out! Basically after checking the data I found out that actually your solution was what I was looking for! Thank you so much for helping me out!

Comment: Awesome, glad to help!